# How can one filter a JSON object to select only specific key/values using jq?

Tags: jq

I'm trying to validate all versions in a `versions.json` file, and get as the output a json with only the invalid versions.

Here's a sample file:

```json
{
  "slamx": "16.4.0 ",
  "sdbe": null,
  "mimir": null,
  "thoth": null,
  "quasar": null,
  "connectors": {
    "s3": "16.0.17",
    "azure": "6.0.17",
    "url": "8.0.2",
    "mongo": "7.0.15"
  }
}
```

I can use the following `jq` script line to do what I want:

```
delpaths([paths(type == "string" and contains(" ") or type == "object" | not)]) 
| delpaths([paths(type == "object" and (to_entries | length == 0))])
```

And use it on a shell like this:

```bash
BAD_VERSIONS=$(jq 'delpaths([paths(type == "string" and contains(" ") or type == "object" | not)]) | delpaths([paths(type == "object" and (to_entries | length == 0))])' versions.json)

if [[ $BAD_VERSIONS != "{}" ]]; then
  echo >&2 $'Bad versions detected in versions.json:\n'"$BAD_VERSIONS"
  exit 1
fi
```

and get this as the output:

```
Bad versions detected in versions.json:
{
  "slamx": "16.4.0 "
}
```

However, that's a very convoluted way of doing the filtering. Instead of just walking the paths tree and just saying "keep this, keep that", I need to create a list of things I do not want and remove them, *twice*.

Given all the path-handling builtins and recursive processing, I can't help but feel that there has to be a better way of doing this, something akin to `select`, but working recursively across the object, but the best I could do was this:

```
. as $input | 
[path(recurse(.[]?)|select(strings|contains("16")))] as $paths | 
reduce $paths[] as $x ({}; . | setpath($x; ($input | getpath($x))))
```

I don't like that for two reasons. First, I'm creating a new object instead of "editing" the old one. Second and foremost, it's full of variables, which points to a severe flow inversion issue, and adds to the complexity.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how to convert it back from the stream but: `jq -c --stream 'select( .[-1] | (type=="string" and contains(" ")) or (type=="object" and length==0) )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@jhnc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878970/how-can-one-filter-a-json-object-to-select-only-specific-key-values-using-jq/56941269#comment100308155_56878970), I found a solution. The trick was using streams, which makes nesting irrelevant -- I can apply filters based solely on the value, and the objects will be recomposed given the key paths.

The first thing I tried did not work, however. This:

```sh
jq -c 'tostream|select(.[-1] | type=="string" and contains(" "))' versions.json
```

returns `[["slamx"],"16.4.0 "]`, which is what I'm searching for. However, I could not fold it back into an object. For that to happen, the stream has to have the "close object" markers -- arrays with just one element, corresponding to the last key of the object being closed. So I changed it to this:

```sh
jq -c  'tostream|select((.[-1] | type=="string" and contains(" ")) or length==1)' versions.json
```

Breaking it down, `.[-1]` selects the last element of the array, which will be the value. Next, `type=="string" and contains(" ")` will select all values which are strings and contain spaces. The last part of the select, `length==1`, keeps all the "end" markers. Interestingly, it works even if the end marker does not correspond to the last key, so this might be brittle.

With that done, I can de-stream it:

```sh
jq -c  'fromstream(tostream|select((.[-1] | type=="string" and contains(" ")) or length==1))' versions.json
```

The jq expression is as follow:

```
fromstream(
    tostream |
    select(
        (
            .[-1] | 
            type=="string" and contains(" ")
        ) or 
        length==1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For objects, the test `to_entries|length == 0` can be abbreviated to `length==0`.
2. If I understand the goal correctly, you could just use `..`, perhaps along the following lines:

```
..
| objects
| with_entries(
    select(( .value|type == "string" and contains(" ")) or (.value|type == "object" and length==0)) )
| select(length>0)
```

### paths

If you want the paths, then consider:

```
([], paths) as $p
| getpath($p)
| objects
| with_entries(
        select(( .value|type == "string" and contains(" ")) or (.value|type == "object" and length==0)) )
| select(length>0) as $x
| {} | setpath($p; $x)
```

With your input modified so that s3 has a trailing blank, the above produces:

```
{"slamx":"16.4.0 "}
{"connectors":{"s3":"16.0.17 "}}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the nested objects. Add a space to `s3`'s version, for example, and you'll see that it prints `{"s3":"16.0.17 "}` (in compact mode) instead of `{"connectors":{"s3":"16.0.17 "}}`.

Comment: I didn't notice from the original problem description that you wanted the full paths.  Please see the update.

Comment: Yeah, but that is pretty much the convoluted solution I had.